# Use an ARSCNView on devices that don't support ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, arscnview

Is it possible to use an `ARSCNView`, configure it with an `ARWorldTrackingConfiguration` for device that support it, and configure it another way for devices that don't support it (with A8 chip and lower) and still have the video render in the background?

```
if ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.isSupported{
    let config=ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    config.planeDetection = .horizontal
    sceneView.session.run(config)
}else if AROrientationTrackingConfiguration.isSupported{
    let config=AROrientationTrackingConfiguration()
    sceneView.session.run(config)
}else{
    print("not supported")
    //what here?  <<<
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a running `ARSession` to drive the camera feed to an `ARSCNView`, to run an `ARSession` you need a supported `ARConfiguration`, and all configurations require A9.

However, if your below-A9 fallback plan is to have a SceneKit view that doesn't get any of ARKit's motion tracking... you don't need ARKit. Just use a regular SceneKit view (`SCNView`). To make the camera feed show up behind your SceneKit content, find the `AVCaptureDevice` for the camera you want, and pass that to the [`background`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscene/1523665-background)`.`[`contents`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterialproperty/1395372-contents) of the scene in your view.

(Using a capture device as a SceneKit background is new in iOS 11. It doesn't appear to be in the docs (yet?), but it's described [in the WWDC17 SceneKit session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017-604/?time=2655).)

---

By the way, there aren't any devices that support orientation tracking but don't support world tracking, so the multiple-branch `if` statement in your question is sort of overkill.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'll try what you said.

Comment: By the way, how do you suggest to pass the camera on the background contents of the `SCNView`? With `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`? Or as I use to do: display the frames in a `GLKView`?

Comment: 1. Use `AVCaptureDevice.default(_:for:position:)` to find the back camera. 2. Set `scene.background.contents` to the AVCaptureDevice object you just got. 3. There's no step three!

Comment: I'm probably missing something. I have a white screen, and if I change the `backgroundColor` to clear it turns black, but still no camera preview.

Comment: See the links in my answer — don't set the `backgroundColor` of the view (which is a property inherited from `UIView` and only takes colors), set the `background` of the `SCNScene` displayed in the view. That's an `SCNMaterialProperty`, meaning you can set its `contents` to any number of things, including colors, images, and `AVCaptureDevice`s.

Answer (score 1):

Below code resolve this issue, it might be broken code

```
let device = sceneView.device!
let maskGeometry = ARSCNFaceGeometry(device: device)!
mask = Mask(geometry: maskGeometry, maskType: maskType)
```

replace with

```
    let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()
    let maskGeometry = ARSCNFaceGeometry(device: device!)!
    mask = Mask(geometry: maskGeometry)
```